# Not getting desired path

Tags: php, url, server

i am using this code

```
<?php $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>
```

this will give me http://209.84.172.15/New/index and i want this http://202.54.151.15/New

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```